# changing cell background colour results in highlighted text

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have the following code ran when creating cells in a table view

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Medicine *medicine = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([medicine isDue] == 1)
    {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[self dueColour]];
        NSLog(@"Due");
    }
    else if([medicine active] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:0])
    {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[self inactiveColour]];
        NSLog(@"Inactive");
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        NSLog(@"Active");
    }
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[medicine name]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Next Due: %@",[medicine nextDueDate]]];
}
```

which is fine, but if i change the the issue or active property, i expect to get the new cell colour, but what i get is the new cell colour, but with the old colour as a text highlight and i can't figure out why.
I know the right colour is being assigned, as when printing out a due and an active medicine i get

> 2013-09-17 23:05:28.121 Medicine Tracker[11611:907] Due 2013-09-17
>
> 23:05:28.124 Medicine Tracker[11611:907] Active

which is correct, but the wrong colours given

Heres an image which might show what i mean better[image]

Comment: You problem is the fact that the label's are using their own background color. Two options; A. set the label (text-)background color to transparent. B. set the label background color to the color you wish to apply to the entire cell-background.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Its strange since in the previous app version the code i had worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is the fact that the label's are using their own background color.

Two options; A. set the label (text-)background color to transparent. B. set the label background color to the color you wish to apply to the entire cell-background.

Option A:

```
[[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Option B:

```
UIColor *backgroundColorNew = nil; 
Medicine *medicine = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([medicine isDue] == 1)
{
    backgroundColorNew = [self dueColour];
    NSLog(@"Due");
}
else if([medicine active] == [NSNumber numberWithInt:0])
{
    backgroundColorNew = [self inactiveColour];
    NSLog(@"Inactive");
}
else
{
    backgroundColorNew = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSLog(@"Active");
}
//set all visibile backgrounds to the new color
[cell setBackgroundColor:backgroundColorNew];
[[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:backgroundColorNew];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:backgroundColorNew];

[[cell textLabel] setText:[medicine name]];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Next Due: %@",[medicine nextDueDate]]];
```

Whereas option B usually results into higher display performance as transparency commonly costs some extra cycles.